# How to read apple HDD on linux without root privileges?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hfs+

My question is very simple. I just want to read my Apple HDD on my linux computer without root privileges.

My goal is only to read and copy some file from my home directory (in Documents). Currently I can read the content of ~/ but I can't read ~/Documents.

Comment: Could you please show us the access rights and owners on the mounted disk? Also what are the `mount` options you use? Please show the output of the command `mount`.

Comment: @pabouk I don't use manually `mount` command. System mounts automatically the HDD. The corresponding lines resulting of the mount command are: `/dev/sdg2 on /var/run/media/xxxx/Macintosh HD type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8)` and `/dev/sdg2 on /run/media/xxxx/Macintosh HD type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: The correct solution is to change the `uid` and `gid` (and possibly `umask`) parameters of the `mount`. Which Linux distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @pabouk Do you think I can change `uid` and `gid` without root privileges? Because it seems that I can't use the `mount`command without root privilges. I am using OpenSuse 12.3.

Comment: Basically you can edit `/etc/fstab` as `root` to allow normal users mount with predefined parameters or maybe you can configure `udisks` (the automatic mounting system). Unfortunately I will be able to write a complete reply only after few hours :(

Comment: @pabouk it does not matter. Currently I have found a temporary solution as I wrote below. I will discuss with my system administrator if we can find a better solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the privileges of everyone to r/w on ~/Documents, chmod should do it for you.

Comment: Are you sure I can't do this without root privileges. In fact the right of the `Document`directory are `drwx------`.

Comment: I agree with Guuk. In this case you cannot change the privileges without root rights. Please add more details if you think we are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found one solution for reading the files (but not writing): download [hfsexplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html). The sofware can be used without root privileges for accessing the files on the Apple hard-drive.

I agree with the fact that it is not a very efficient solution but it works for copy some files.